# First several requests return 500 Unable to Download OpenID Connect Configuration, Then Succeeds

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect

I have an API in Azure (App Service) that uses an App Registration pointing at AzureAD as the Identity Provider.  It works-ish.  The problem I'm having is that after the app sits for a few seconds, the first few calls (with a valid bearer token) come back with a status "500 Unable to download OpenID Connection Configuration."  I click send a few more times in postman and it starts working... 200 response with the proper response payload.

How can I help my app retain the OpenID configuration information so I don't run into this problem every time the API hasn't been hit in a while?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to write your own retry-logic that will allow the AddOpenIDConnect/AddJwtBearer handler to handle your situation better when the discovery endpoint is not responding.

```
.AddMyJwtBearer(opt =>
  {
       opt.BackchannelHttpHandler = new BackChannelListener();
       opt.BackchannelTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60); //60 seconds 
       ...
  }
```

The backchannelhandler is the client that will request the discovery document.

A sample handler is provided below, which will just log these requests. That in itself can be useful. But inside it, you could try to add your own retry logic, perhaps together with Polly?

```
/// <summary>
/// Backchannel listener, that will log requests made to our IdentityServer 
/// From the IdentityServer in production training class https://www.tn-data.se
/// </summary>
public class BackChannelListener : DelegatingHandler
{
    public BackChannelListener() : base(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BackChannelListener");
        Console.WriteLine("@@@@ SendASync: " + request.RequestUri);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        var result = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        result.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("@@@@ success: " + result.IsFaulted);
            Console.WriteLine("@@@@ loadtime: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("@@@@ url: " + request.RequestUri);

            Serilog.Log.Logger.ForContext("SourceContext", "BackChannelListener")
                              .ForContext("url", request.RequestUri)
                              .ForContext("loadtime", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + " ms")
                              .ForContext("success", result.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                              .Information("Loading IdentityServer configuration");
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

This picture shows the timeline, and also important to realise that if the dicovery document is not found, it will retry ever 30 seconds I think.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for spending the time on this answer, @Tore.  Do you know if it is the calling application or the called application that tries to download the openid configuration?  It seems there should be a way to just download this when the application starts and just place it in an easy-to-retrieve place (i.e. in memory) to eliminate the need for something like this.  Is that not the case?  The information in the configuration is essentially static.  Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Both the client (AddOpenIDConnect) and APIs (AddJwtBearer) that depends on OpenID-connect typically download the discovery data at startup (when the first token is handled)  and then it downloads/refresh the data each 24h.

Comment: see my updated answer. feel free to accept my answer if it has helped you.